# Preview is hanging up and needs to be forced-quit

Tags: preview

I found this answer elsewhere on this forum, and it seemed promising, but I don't seem to have any of these files on my computer. The Caches and Preferences folders don't have files that reference Preview, and I don't seem to have Container or Saved Application State folders. Could someone suggest another fix (or tell me if I'm doing something wrong looking for the files)? I'm running 10.8.5 on a MacBook Pro. Thanks much!

Probably resetting the Preview could solve that problem

Delete following in your ~/Library

Caches/com.apple.Preview
Containers/com.apple.Preview
Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist
Preferences/com.apple.Preview.SandboxedPersistentURLs.LSSharedFileList.plist
Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState

Restart preview and test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out. I saw another post about pasting the path into the Go menu, so I did that, found the Containers folder, found and deleted the com.apple.Preview folder, restarted Preview, and it seems to be working better now. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Make sure to mark this as answered.